# Streaming data over bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth, streaming, signal-processing, data-acquisition

I'm working on a project that streams data to a laptop. The data is an analog signal with 5 kHz bandwidth (almost like audio) that is digitized at first and should be transmitted over a bluetooth module to a laptop. I've searched a lot about modules that use this protocol to stream data. I figured out simple bluetooth modules like hc-05 or hc-06 because of their limitation of packet's size and interval time can't be used for this application. It has been suggested to use audio bluetooth module like bc127 and csr because of their appropriate sample rate (I want more than 20 kS/s) and their applications so I want to use them but not for an audio signal for my signal. Now I want to ask you:

1- Can I use these modules to acquire my signal (that is not an audio signal) wireless?

2- Do these modules compress signal for transmission and should I decompress it in receiver side (I know they have some audio DSP but I don't know what are they and their function)?

3- Can laptop's bluetooth hardware receive this data without any problem? If not, what are alternatives?

4- is there any filtering in the proccess? i mean filter about voise band(300 Hz ~ 4 kHz)

thank you.